# Can't get Coverage to work in PyDev, "File has no statistics"

Tags: python, code-coverage, pydev, coverage.py, python-coverage

I can't get Coverage to work with PyDev. Every file I run shows up with: "File has no statistics."

I'm following the instructions by checking 'Enable code coverage for new launches', and dragging the folder to analyze over to the Code Coverage window.

I've successfully installed coverage. After that, I refreshed my Python Interpreter settings, where the coverage folder shows up automatically.

I've also tried to add the coverage folder to my project's External Libraries. Didn't work either...

Thanks in advance for any tips that might guide me in the right direction.

- Coverage version 3.5.2 (also tried the recommended 3.4 to no avail)
- PyDev version: 2.6.0
- Eclipse version: 3.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be due to your file path containing spaces.  See [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3535032&group_id=85796&atid=577329) here.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks!