# PyDev Code Coverage: “File has no statistics”

Tags: python, code-coverage, pydev

I saw a similar post here [Can't get Coverage to work in PyDev, "File has no statistics"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130124/cant-get-coverage-to-work-in-pydev-file-has-no-statistics) , but I have a different issue (my folder names do not contain any spaces). Basically I followed this video http://pydev.org/video_pydev_20.html - step-by-step and I have an identical code and folder structure. After dropping a folder for analysis I get "File has no statistics". In original video it starts at minute 4:00 . I have

- Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Kepler Release Build id: 20130614-0229
- Pydev, which I downloaded and installed via Eclipse Marketplace just today
- Python 2.7.5 (official)
- Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5

Comment: Even with some other current versions I can't get this to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470813/code-coverage-not-working-with-pydev for details.